# Django - set DateTimeField default to timezone.datetime.max

Tags: django, datetime

I'm trying to set the default value for a datetime field to the max date `timezone.datetime.max`

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone

class Item(models.Model):
  id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
  deleted  = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.datetime.max)
```

And i'm getting this error when ever i try to save a new object to the db

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py:903:
RuntimeWarning: DateTimeField Item.deleted received a naive datetime (9999-12-31 23:59:59.999999) while time zone support is active. RuntimeWarning)
```

So reading the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/timezones/) on this issue i'v set `USE_TZ=True` and i've got `pytz` installed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`timezone.datetime` - this is regular python `datetime.datetime` module which is imported in `django.utils.timezone` and it returns regular datetime, so you need to make it aware:

```
timezone.make_aware(timezone.datetime.max, timezone.get_default_timezone())
```

Comment: I don't see why this answer was accepted, it doesn't really solve the issue, because timezone.make_aware does not work with dates out of range (datetime.max in this case)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, this was my fix

```
timezone.datetime.max.replace(tzinfo=timezone.get_default_timezone())
```

with "datetime.min" I had another year -1 issue, which I resolved with this:

```
timezone.datetime.min.replace(tzinfo=timezone.utc)
```